# VB.Net process exits as soon as I attempt to read standard output or error

Tags: vb.net, process, redirectstandardoutput

### Initial Problem

I apologize if this issue has been raised and addressed elsewhere; I searched this site, and Google at large without any luck.

I'm trying to write a simple VB.Net Windows Forms Application to allow a user to run the Windows File Compare program (fc.exe) with a very simple GUI ("browse" buttons to select files, checkboxes to select modifiers, and a textbox for the output).

The problem is that whenever I try to read the standard output or error from the process, it immediately stops, and nothing is output.  I've verified that the process arguments are correct by setting "createnowindow" to False and not redirecting Output or Errors.

To see if the process is actually running or not, I put a "while" loop after proc.start:

```
Do While proc.HasExited = False
textbox.AppendText(i & vbNewLine)
i += 1
Loop
```

If the process runs normally, I get a count up to about 80 or 90.  If I do anything at all with the standardoutput or standarderror, the textbox only shows the initial value of "0".  By "anything at all", I mean assigning the `proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd` to a variable.  If I use `proc.StandardOutput.Peek`, it returns a `-1` and the loop remains at 0.

I've noticed that if I only redirect either Output *or* Error (but not both), and I enable the process to open a new window, the new window is empty and immediately exits (even if I'm not attempting to read the redirected stream in my code), whereas if neither is redirected, it displays a few pages of results, then exits.  I don't know if this is normal, or if the File Compare executable is somehow mixing the Output and Error streams to generate its output, or if something like that is even possible.

I'm extremely new to coding in general (I've been working with VB.net for about a month, and that's the extent of my programming experience), so my I'm aware that my troubleshooting and assumptions may be completely off base, and I appreciate any assistance anyone can provide.  As it is, I'm completely floundering, and my inexperience is making it difficult to look for alternatives (for instance, I can't figure out how to correctly handle asynchronous output).  For reference, here's my embarrassingly clunky code as it currently stands:

```
Dim cmdinput As String = """" & file1path & """" & " " & """" & file2path & """"
    Dim cmdmods As String = " "
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim proc As New Process
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Windows\System32\fc.exe"
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmdinput & cmdmods
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    proc.Start()
    proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()

    Do While proc.HasExited = False
        scanbox.AppendText(i & vbNewLine)

        i += 1
    Loop
```

### Possible Solution

After Hans Passant pointed out that I should be seeing errors, if nothing else, I messed around with my code and was able to get a result, though a less than optimal one.  Instead of running FC.exe directly, I ran CMD.exe.  I had tried this before with no luck, but that's because CMD.exe doesn't accept "fc " as process.startinfo.arguments.

I passed the "fc " to cmd.exe with proc.standardinput.writeline().  At this point I was able to read CMD.exe's redirected output.  I still have no idea why I can't directly read FC.exe, but this is a pretty good band-aid in the meantime.  On the off chance that anyone else feels the need to add a GUI to a perfectly good command-line executable and runs into problems, here's my code:

```
Public Sub compare()
    Dim cmdinput As String = "fc " & """" & file1path & """" & " " & """" & file2path & """"
    Dim cmdmods As String = " "
    Dim proc As New Process
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmdinput & cmdmods
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    proc.Start()
    proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(cmdinput)
    proc.StandardInput.Close()
    scanbox.AppendText(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd)
    proc.WaitForExit()
    proc.Close()
    proc.Dispose()
End Sub
```

I Greatly appreciate the patience from  Hans Passant and Dan Verdolino in offering suggestions to my rambling question.  I've been hammering my head against a wall for a week trying to kludge together some way of doing this.

Comment: You are forgetting to read StandardError.  You've got an error.

Comment: If I read either StandardError or StandardOutput (or both), it fails.  No error is generated, but no output/error is returned, and my loop remains at 0.

Comment: Well, there should be an error.  You passed "fc" as an argument to fc.exe, it should complain that it doesn't know what you mean.

Comment: Sorry that's another leftover of my many debugging rewrites...I had a long, confusing debug string in place of "cmdinputs" to save me from having to select files each time, and I removed it when I posted the question so it would be a little more readable.  The "fc" is from my attempt at wrapping the entire thing in "cmd.exe".  When I do that, I can see the command prompt as my StandardOutput, but FC itself still returns nothing...sorry for the confusion there.

EDIT:  I removed the "fc" from that string in the pasted code.

Comment: Now that you mention it, though, I *did* botch my debug string at first, and even though FC should have been returning an error for "too few files", I saw the same exact symptoms that I do now, and it still didn't return anything on StandardError or StandardOutput.  I was only able to find out by setting CreateNoWindow and RedirectStandardOutput and RedirectStandardError to False, and leaping on the "print screen" button for the split second that the FC window was up.  EDIT: And I just tried sending it complete gibberish as an argument, and I'm seeing exactly the same symptoms.

Comment: An alternative is to make a .bat file and run COMP http://www.easydos.com/comp.html

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't heard of COMP.  Now that I know how to retrieve the results into a string, I may work this into my program to give it a bit more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Instead of running FC.exe directly, I ran CMD.exe.  I had tried this before with no luck, but that's because CMD.exe doesn't accept "fc (args)" as process.startinfo.arguments.

I passed the "fc (args)" to cmd.exe with proc.standardinput.writeline().  At this point I was able to read CMD.exe's redirected output.  I still have no idea why I can't directly read FC.exe's output or errors, but this is a pretty good band-aid in the meantime.  On the off chance that anyone else feels the need to add a GUI to a perfectly good command-line executable and runs into problems, here's my code:

```
Public Sub compare()
    Dim cmdinput As String = "fc " & """" & file1path & """" & " " & """" & file2path & """"
    Dim cmdmods As String = " "
    Dim proc As New Process
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmdinput & cmdmods
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    proc.Start()
    proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(cmdinput)
    proc.StandardInput.Close()
    scanbox.AppendText(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd)
    proc.WaitForExit()
    proc.Close()
    proc.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Delegate Sub InvokeWithString(ByVal text As String)
Public Sub StartFC()
    Private psi As ProcessStartInfo
    Private cmd As Process

Dim CMDINPUT As String = "fc " & """" & file1path & """" & " " & """" & file2path & """"
       Dim FileToHit As String = "c:\windows\system32\fc.exe "

 psi = New ProcessStartInfo(FileToHit)
        Dim systemencoding As System.Text.Encoding = _
            System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)

        With psi
            .Arguments = CMDINPUT 
            .UseShellExecute = False   ' Required for redirection
            .RedirectStandardError = True
            .RedirectStandardOutput = True
            .RedirectStandardInput = True
            .CreateNoWindow = True
            .StandardOutputEncoding = systemencoding  
            .StandardErrorEncoding = systemencoding
        End With

        ' EnableraisingEvents is required for Exited event
        cmd = New Process With {.StartInfo = psi, .EnableRaisingEvents = True}
        AddHandler cmd.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf Async_Data_Received
        AddHandler cmd.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf Async_Data_Received
        AddHandler cmd.Exited, AddressOf CMD_Exited
        cmd.Start()
        pID1 = cmd.Id
        cmd.BeginOutputReadLine()
        cmd.BeginErrorReadLine()
        Me.txtInputStringIn.Select() ' textbox where you can send more commands. 
End Sub
'This event fires when process exited
 Private Sub CMD_Exited(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        'Me.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Process is exited.")
    End Sub
'This part calls when Output received 
    Private Sub Async_Data_Received(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
        Me.Invoke(New InvokeWithString(AddressOf Sync_Output), e.Data)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Sync_Output(ByVal text As String)
'an output textbox will show the output of the command prompt.
        txtOutPut.AppendText(text & Environment.NewLine)
        txtOutPut.ScrollToCaret()
    End Sub
```